# Angular2 parse directive template ng-container

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am new to angular2 and tried with dynamic form and its field generation by referring this [URL](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms). And i got the form as expected.

Since the dynamic form component render the field one by one using ng-container as shown below by loop it

```
<ng-container
        *ngFor="let field of config;"
        dynamicField
        [config]="field"
        [group]="form">
      </ng-container>
```

I am using the form template as shown below

```
<dynamic-form
        [config]="config"
        #form="dynamicForm"
        (submit)="submit($event)">
      </dynamic-form>
```

I want to render the template inside dynamic-form as two column not one by one.Basically i want to define the html field position placing inside dynamic-form directive. For example

```
<dynamic-form
    [config]="config"
    #form="dynamicForm"
    (submit)="submit($event)">
    <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="FIRST_NAME"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="LAST_NAME"></div>
        </div>
  </dynamic-form>
```

How `<ng-container>` could help to replace the respective field which we given in our directive template. Or Suggest best way to render html in defined position dynamically  using dynamic-form component.

Expected output,
[image]

Please advise

Comment: Which result do you expect?

Comment: @yurzui How could we control the placing of field position. Since ng-container just render it one by one.

Comment: @yurzui For your reference, attached the screen

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create directive that will keep reference to `ViewContainerRef`. This way it will be possible to place the field wherever you want.

So let's try to describe how we can do that.

First, create directive like:

**dynamic-form-field-place.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamic-form-placeId]'
})
export class DynamicFormFieldPlaceDirective {
  @Input('dynamic-form-placeId') placeId: string;

  constructor(public vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

The directive just takes `dynamic-form-placeId` `@Input` and we also inject `ViewContainer` to get hold reference to it. As you will see later it will be used in `DynamicFieldDirective` provided by Todd Motto.

After that we mark places for our dynamic fields

```
<dynamic-form
    [config]="config"
    #form="dynamicForm"
    (submit)="submit($event)">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <ng-container dynamic-form-placeId="FirstName"></ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <ng-container dynamic-form-placeId="LastName"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <ng-container dynamic-form-placeId="Gender"></ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <ng-container dynamic-form-placeId="Food"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</dynamic-form>
```

then modify

**dynamic-form.component.html**

```
<form
    class="dynamic-form"
    [formGroup]="form"
    (submit)="handleSubmit($event)">
  <ng-content></ng-content> // we transclude markup
  <ng-container
        *ngFor="let field of config;"
        dynamicField
        [container]="containers[field.name]" // and pass viewContainerRef
        [config]="field"
        [group]="form">
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

**dynamic-form.component.ts**

```
@ContentChildren(DynamicFormFieldPlaceDirective) places: 
                           QueryList<DynamicFormFieldPlaceDirective>;

containers = {};

ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.places.forEach(x => this.containers[x.placeId] = x.vcRef);
}
```

And finally let's modify `DynamicFieldDirective`

**dynamic-field.directive.ts**

```
@Input() container: ViewContainerRef;

ngOnInit() {
  ...
  const container = this.container || this.vcRef;
  ...
}
```

In the preceding code i use `ViewContainerRef` that was provided by us earlier.

If you want to look at completed code just open

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/RbnEmYJ0CzHKcP96FkC3?p=preview)**

Comment: Can you reproduce it in my plunker?

Comment: yes https://plnkr.co/edit/2AamchyRjbsZgLRdcwT4?p=info but got http error for api call!!!... Here i want to make field readonly initially. so i will need another config call mode as edit/view if it is edit then we can show as it is with prepopulated data but when it is in view config we should show field as read only :)

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/XMOxmXx3wNkiQGYKkh1R?p=preview What is the problem with disabling?

Comment: no disabling, just text content (input value which is assigned) with label

Comment: @yurzuri That is input component itself should be render based on edit or view mode. Input directive template has to be conditionally rendered

Comment: I don't see where you have view mode

Comment: @yurzuri, we will have new field interface as 'mode'. This mode will be default to edit. If i set to view in config, the fields(select/input etc) should be render with label and its value but not render with disabled attribute

Comment: @mymotherland https://plnkr.co/edit/qozudmtyGlNBs0MNaJDj?p=preview See `form-input.component.ts`

Comment: wow really simple approach...i was thinking  too complicate. thanks